# How to read a digital PIC port into a single variable?

Tags: c, pic, pic18

I have a practice exam question that asks me to read PORTB input logic levels into a single char variable called result. (On a PIC18F252). I had some ideas for this but I haven't got answers to check so I'm not sure whats right. This is what I was thinking at first, but I don't know if calling PORTB in a bitwise OR operation would actually retrieve all the input levels:

```
void setup(){
   TRISB = 0xFF; //Set all portB pins as inputs
}

void main(){
   char result;
   result |= PORTB;  //OR the value of the PORTB register into the result variable
}
```

Would this be right? And if not can anyone help me find a better way to do it?

Comment: Remember that uninitialized local variables *are* uninitialized. They will have an *indeterminate* value (which might seem as random or garbage).

Comment: @visibleman I'm assuming you're saying its wrong but you don't know what would be right? If so, could you explain why you think its wrong?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Problem is that in the question it states that result has been initialized earlier in the theoretical program, I only need to write my answer as the actual reading of PORTB. I know I wrote it all here but its more because I often get people being very snappy with me on here if I don't post full code

Answer (score 0):

After playing around some more, I've found that it was an error in the question that was causing the problem.
`result |= PORTB` will actually work fine, but `result` should be an `unsigned char`, not a `char` as the question stated. This is because PORTB and unsigned chars both contain an 8-bit value (0-255), but a `char` handles 7 bit values (-128 to 127).

Comment: It's implementation-define if `char` is signed or unsigned.